# How can I get MAC Address without using the IP in Java?

Tags: java, tcp, java-7, ethernet, mac-address

How can I found the MAC address of a network card without knowing and using the IP address in Java?

Comment: [tag:jsp] has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `NetworkInterface.getHardwareAddress`. You can get the list of all network cards with `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()`.

you can use this code for knowing MAC Address.

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
NetworkInterface nwi = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address);
byte mac[] = nwi.getHardwareAddress();
System.out.println(mac);
```

Comment: I've tried like that but it doesn't work because it takes first the address of Local Loopback in linux. And to be more specific I need just the internet address of the network card which is connected on internet  on linux, because on windows works the method gived by you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use system command like below(if you on `nix` systems, if your os is windows use `ipconfig` in a similar way):

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p = r.exec("ifconfig -u |grep ether");
p.waitFor();
BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line = "";

while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
  System.out.println(line);
}

b.close();
```

On my system it gives:

```
ether 28:37:37:15:3b:31 
ether b2:00:10:65:56:41 
...
```

Notice that there are maybe many MAC addresses, the Bluetooth, the Ethernet, the WIFI and so on.